# Android how to add ic_lancher on action bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I am using android navigation Drawer. created by eclipse. I want to add my ic_launcher on the action bar. as it would normally show.

I also set the min API to 14.

styles
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/orange_dark</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/orange_dark</item>
</style>
```

here is my manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" 
        android:name=".gears.MyApplication">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call this on your toolbar/actionbar `toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`